# How do I update a solution to latest in AnkhSVN?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

I'm using AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2013 and grabbing code from an Unfuddle repository. I'm not a dev, but my job is dev-adjacent and I'd like to be able to look at people's code.

In VS, I can figure out how to get a local copy of the solution file using the Unfuddle repository URL, but I can't figure out how to update the solution to the latest version. When I right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer, there's no "update" option, and in the Pending Changes window, "Update" is grayed out.

So when I want to get latest, I go to "Repository Explorer" in VS, click the connect icon, enter the URL for the repository. Then I right-click on the file I want to copy over, and select "Copy to Working Copy". I choose a location, and VS informs me that it is "not in a working copy; would I like to export the file instead?" I say yes, and it copies everything over.

I have to do this whole process every time I want to get latest. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! The solution wasn't added to Subversion. I needed to go to the Working Copy Explorer, right-click the directory in question, select "Add Solution to Subversion", then enter the repository URL.